# C# how to adjust textbox property in a form from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, object, properties, controls

i still cant get how to access the controls in the form from another class.im new to c# so my "try and error" method is not actually working.

can anyone give me a simple guide?

this is my code snippet

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            print pr = new print();
            pr.p();

        }

    }
}
```

This is class print:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class print 
    {
        public print()
        {

        }

        public void p()
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.textBox1.Text = "change text";

        }     

    }

}
```

as you can see, im trying to change the textBox1 property in the print class.but when i compile it,im thrown with a System.StackOverflowException!

im getting frustrated now because i cant access it from another class.

can anyone give me a step by step on how to call it from the print class?i tried many steps from the internet but i just cant get it.

btw, i did make the modifier for the textbox to public.

Comment: You need to step back a little and read up on how objects, classes, and constructors work in C#. Your difficulties stem from your lack of a clear understanding of those very important base concepts. Understanding them will give you the foundations you need to solve this problem and much more.

Comment: I have answered below, but I would also like to make a small comment on your code format.  For example, your method 'p' is poorly named.  Your method names should be descriptive, such as PrintDocument().  The textbox could be something like:  txtUserNameInput.  Also look into the correct casing for class/method names.  Your 'print' class should really be Print.  It's good to get into these habits early, they will become second nature.

Comment: @Darren Young, at this point code formatting is the least of the OP's problems. Eventually he/she will get there. +1 anyway

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, i agree with your advise since i am really new to all of this and i dont really get the full understanding yet. thats why i think i cant  even resolve simple problems yet.but thanks for your advise.

Comment: @Darren Young i thank you very much for your comments and i do notice my mistakes but this code snippet is not actually the full coding so i just make it simple so that i can make my problem more clearer but again i thank you. i have been commented like this and im working on it.

Comment: @tzup - I agree, however I wish I knew about correct formatting when I first started.  It would save a lot of embarrassment when I look back at my legacy code :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `print.p` method creates a new form, and the form's constructor calls the `print.p` method again. Which then creates another new form, whose constructor calls the `print.p` method again, loop over and over. That's where the `StackOverflowException` is coming from.

The solution is to get a book that teaches object-oriented programming. I know that probably sounds snarky or unhelpful, but none of the answers you'll get on a Q&A website can adequately explain to you why what you're trying to do is a bad idea. External helper classes like `print` should *not* be able to mess with private members of your form class. Instead, you should call public methods on your form class that make these modifications.

The quick-and-dirty fix requires that you figure out a way to get a reference to the instance of your form class in the `print.p` method. That's the only way you're going to be able to call methods on *that* object, rather than creating a *new* object of that class. One way is to pass a reference in to the method as a parameter:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        print pr = new print();
        pr.p(this);
    }
}

class print 
{
    public print()
    {

    }

    public void p(Form frm)
    {
        frm.textBox1.Text = "change text";
    }     
}
```

Also, as a somewhat irrelevant stylistic note, you should be aware that almost all coding guidelines/conventions for C# (and the .NET platform) require that the names of classes and methods be PascalCased, rather than camelCased. So, your `print` class should actually be named `Print`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is simply pass a reference through to the new form.

```
print pr = new print(textbox);

public print(Textbox textbox)
{
   //do something with textbox.

}
```

There are a number of design patterns however, that can help with this, such as MVP or MVVM.  However, they may be a little advanced for your current level.  If this is only a simple small project, then the code above will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is problematic for other reasons (@CodyGray explains the why, which is the reason you're getting a `StackOverflowException`), but in general you can use a property to allow access, without exposing the actual `TextBox` control itself; see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for plenty details, but for example:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        }

        public string FormText
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
            set { textBox1.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in order to use this property:

```
public void p()
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.FormText = "change text";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since there is at least one nitpick via comments, and sufficient incentive for at least one person to find that point 'great', I'll also offer a little different approach, still using the property...

Let's imagine the goal is that you want to `set` text in `p`, we'll just return what we need:

```
public string p()
{
    return "change text";
}
```

So that:

```
myFormReferenceSomewhereNotInPrintClass.FormText = myPrintClassInstance.p();
```

Or, you want to `get`, or *use* the text in `p`:

```
public void p(string text)
{
    //do your thing with the text
}
```

So that:

```
myPrintClassInstance.p(myFormReferenceSomewhereNotInPrintClass.FormText);
```

Comment: @Timothy: It _does_, see: `Form1 f = new Form1();`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `StackOverFlowException` because you create a new *instance* of `print` in `Form1` using this code:

```
print pr = new print();
```

Then in the constructor in `print`, you create a new instance of `Form1` like this:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
```

which creates a new instance of `print`, which creates a new instance of `Form1`, which creates a new instance of `print`, which creates a new instance of `Form1`, which...

You have created an infinite loop, which kills the Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, not sure why you want to do it like this (I wouldn't) but here you go:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        print pr = new print();
        pr.p(this);
    }
}

public class print 
{
    public print() {}

    public void p(Form1 f)
    {
        f.textBox1.Text = "change text";
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not reference UI element properties cross-class like this, it's bad practice.

a better way to do this would be :

form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            print pr = new print();
            textBox1.Text = pr.p();
        }

    }
}
```

class print:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class print 
    {
        public print()
        {

        }

        public string p()
        {
            return "change text";
        }     

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            print pr = new print(this);
            pr.p();

        }
```

and in print class use this to get the form

```
{
Form fpassed;

           public print(Form f)
            {
               fpassed = f;

            }

            public void p(Form f)
            {

                f.textBox1.Text = "change text";

            }     
}
```

can call it by p(fpassed);

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MainForm frm; 

public MainForm(){ 
    frm = this; 
    Yes() 
} 

public Yes(){ 
    frm.textbox1.text = ":D"; 
}
```